# cannot boot after update

Tags: boot, updates

I am a beginner user of Ubuntu. I updated it and the following problem occurred while booting.

```
[328.626105] type=1400 audit(1428046501.300:67): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1435 comm=" apparmor_parser"
```

What should I do? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> cupsd is the scheduler for the Common UNIX Printing System. It implements a printing system based upon the Internet Printing Protocol, version 1.1. If no options are specified on the command-line then the default configuration file (usually /etc/cups/cupsd.conf) will be used.

It propably has nothing to do with Your hung.
Try to load older kernel (hit and hold Shift - as far as i remember) while system boots. When GRUB menu load, select older kernel and let us know what happens.

If You can load into linux, copy and paste 'older kernel log' - dmesg's from /var/log.

Comment: I loaded an older kernel and restarted. Now it's booting properly. Should I update again or leave it as it is? Btw thanks for help :)

Comment: check Your old kernel log what really cause problems - You can copy it and paste into Your first post. No problemo, You can vote my post ;)